# Creative Exchange Live Gulp "unable to verify the first certificate"

Tags: sxa, gulp, creative-exchange

After following the configuration steps of the Creative Exchange Live, I'm trying to run the gulp tasks through Visual Studio Code but it is throwing a certificate error when uploading:

> [17:51:24] Starting 'watch-gulp'...
>
> upload failed:Error: unable to verify the first certificate

I'm pointing to an HTTPS instance with self-signed certificate.
Versions: Sitecore 9.1, SXA 1.8, node.js 10.15.0

Answer (score 2):

Solved this by using

> strictSSL: false

in every file upload/delete post/get because I'm using a self-signed certificate.

I changed the following files in the gulp\util folder inside the theme root folder:
- requestChangeFile.js
- requestChangeTemplate.js
- requestDeleteFile.js

search for 'url: url' and add to the request get/post call the parameter 'strictSSL: false'. Example:

```
request.post({
            url: url,
            formData: formData,
            strictSSL: false 
        }, function(err, httpResponse, body) { 
          ... 
        });
```

I've found this solution in https://stackoverflow.com/a/41986721/1728196

> "setting strictSSL to false will not force request package to validate the certificate"